# UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xcd in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python

```
@staticmethod
def __csv_from_excel(filename, datapath):  # read from datapath; write to filename
    if (datapath[-4:]) == "xlsx":
        try:
            wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(datapath)
        except KeyError:
            fix_xlsx(filename)
            wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(datapath)
        filenames = []
        sheets = wb.sheetnames
        for sheet in sheets:
            sh = wb[str(sheet)]
            with open(filename[:-4] + sheet + ".csv", 'tw', newline='') as f:
                filenames.append(filename[:-4] + sheet + ".csv")
                wr = csv.writer(f, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, delimiter=";")
                for row in sh.rows:
                    temp = []
                    for cell in row:
                        temp.append(cell.value)
                    wr.writerow(temp)
                f.close()
        return filenames
    elif (datapath[-4:]) == ".xls":
        wb = xlrd.open_workbook(datapath)
        sheetlist = wb.sheet_names()
        filenames = []
        for sheet in sheetlist:
            sh = wb.sheet_by_name(sheet)
            with open(filename[:-4] + sheet + ".csv", 'tw', newline='') as f:
                filenames.append(filename[:-4] + sheet + ".csv")
                wr = csv.writer(f, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, delimiter=";")
                for rownum in range(sh.nrows):
                    wr.writerow(sh.row_values(rownum))
                f.close()
        return filenames
```

Мне приходится обрабатывать отчеты, сформированные кажется в 95м екселе, там есть невидимый символ, который мешает открыть его в питоне.(UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xcd in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)) Не открывается ни через xlrd, ни как com объект. Однако если открыть отчет в современном екселе и пересохранить его, то в дальнейшем мой код спокойно работает с ним. К сожалению нужно работать с большим количеством отчетов, которые нет возможности отфильтровать. 
Кто-нибудь знает как можно исправить?
полный текст ошибки:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/4r4r5/PycharmProjects/untitled2/Main.py", line 8, in <module>
    matcher.rename_drugs()
  File "C:\Users\4r4r5\PycharmProjects\untitled2\Matcher.py", line 212, in rename_drugs
    self.__directory + file)  # for files from directory creates csv copy
  File "C:\Users\4r4r5\PycharmProjects\untitled2\Matcher.py", line 133, in __csv_from_excel
    wb = xlrd.open_workbook(datapath)
  File "C:\Users\4r4r5\PycharmProjects\untitled2\venv\lib\site-packages\xlrd\__init__.py", line 157, in open_workbook
    ragged_rows=ragged_rows,
  File "C:\Users\4r4r5\PycharmProjects\untitled2\venv\lib\site-packages\xlrd\book.py", line 120, in open_workbook_xls
*** No CODEPAGE record, no encoding_override: will use 'ascii'
*** No CODEPAGE record, no encoding_override: will use 'ascii'
    bk.get_sheets()
  File "C:\Users\4r4r5\PycharmProjects\untitled2\venv\lib\site-packages\xlrd\book.py", line 723, in get_sheets
    self.get_sheet(sheetno)
  File "C:\Users\4r4r5\PycharmProjects\untitled2\venv\lib\site-packages\xlrd\book.py", line 714, in get_sheet
    sh.read(self)
  File "C:\Users\4r4r5\PycharmProjects\untitled2\venv\lib\site-packages\xlrd\sheet.py", line 820, in read
    strg = unpack_string(data, 6, bk.encoding or bk.derive_encoding(), lenlen=2)
  File "C:\Users\4r4r5\PycharmProjects\untitled2\venv\lib\site-packages\xlrd\biffh.py", line 250, in unpack_string
    return unicode(data[pos:pos+nchars], encoding)
  File "C:\Users\4r4r5\PycharmProjects\untitled2\venv\lib\site-packages\xlrd\timemachine.py", line 31, in <lambda>
    unicode = lambda b, enc: b.decode(enc)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xcd in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: Полный текст ошибки добавьте в вопрос.Если исключение вылетает на строке с `writerow`, то очевидно, что нужно указать кодировку при открытии csv-файла.

Comment: добавил полный текст ошибки, в начале файла указано # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

Answer (score 0):

Ваша проблема описана в [документации](https://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/unicode.html). Попробуйте явно задать кодировку, в старых файлах она скорее всего cp1251:

```
wb = xlrd.open_workbook(datapath, encoding_override="cp1251")
```

Comment: вопрос решен, спасибо

Comment: @dimonamana если ответ помог вам, [отметьте его решением](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).